# click event for multiple buttons on grid asp.net using c#

Tags: c#

I have multiple buttons on gridview.If i select any button then label must be generated at the bottom of the grid.How do i implement this for asp.net using c#?

Comment: You should specify how did you defined those buttons or eventually put here the markup for the grid.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the data grid as a data key set in asp and then in c sharp, have a gridview_rowcommand activate when a button has been clicked within the table cells for command activation...  And just set the command to a label.

For more:
http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=5066444